# Ringer sound volume start with low for the moment on Moto G4 and E4?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have to notify the user on particular event. The notification should be like ringer even if headphones are plugged in and the user is away from the phone it should be played on Loud Speaker.

Hence I am using Audio stream type as `AudioManager.STREAM_RING` which can be heard on Phones loudspeaker even when headphoens are on.

The problem I am facing is when these notifications are played on Moto G4 & E4 it starts with low volume ( Barely audible ) then in moment plays with normal loud ringer sound.

My code is as below,

Code to stop the player :

```
if (mPlayer != null && mPLayer.isPlaying()) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
}
```

Code to play the bell sound :

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE);
if (am != null) {
            switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
                case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
                    return;
            }
        }
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to beep " + what + ", " + extra);
                if (mp.isPlaying())
                    mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                return true;
            }
        });
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor file = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(R.raw.stop_sound);
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(file.getFileDescriptor(), file.getStartOffset(), file.getLength());
            } finally {
                file.close();
            }
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            Log.w(TAG, ioe);
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
```

What can I do to prevent this from happening? I am not able to find any custom settings on these devices which can be changed for such behaviour.